# firebase + express + minInstances

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have an express app running on firebase, I want it to have the  `minInstances:1` config

Currently I Use:

```
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/http
export const xx = onRequest(app);
```

Only examples I can find are for individual functions:

```
functions.runWith({ minInstances: minInstancesConfig}).https....
```

how can I wrap the `onRequest(app)` with the minInstances config?

*Also I saw a suggestion about using the Cloud Scheduler for short intervals, I tried it and it just drives the server crazy:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as the [example using req and res in the documentaion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#keep_a_minimum_number_of_instances_warm). Just give your app instead of the function callback.

```
functions
    .runWith({ minInstances: minInstancesConfig})
    .https
    .onRequest(app)
```

The addition of `runWith` in the chain of calls here doesn't change the way `onRequest` receives parameters.  It just changes the way to resulting container behaves under load.

Comment: Error: Cannot set CPU on the functions xx because they are GCF Gen 1. The functions is Gen1 and the onRequest directly is Gen2

Comment: The fact that you're using v2 should have been mentioned explicitly in the question since they both use the function name "onRequest".

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job:

```
export const xx = onRequest({
    minInstances: 1,
}, app);
```